# meteor add momentjs:moment failing

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I cannot get momentjs added to my Meteor project. I am presented with the following output but I do not know how to fix. App runs fine with momentjs removed from the packages file. Any suggestions?

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While loading package momentjs:moment@2.15.2:
   error: Command failed:
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd
   rebuild --update-binary
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download:
   https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.14/fse-v1.0.14-node
-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14 and
   node@4.6.1 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with
   node-gyp)
   gyp ERR! configure error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable
   "C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\python\python.exe",
   you can set the PYTHON env variable.
   gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython
   (C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
   gyp ERR! stack     at
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
   gyp ERR! stack     at
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
   "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
   "--module=C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_mome
nt\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-mkvu1b\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\bindin
g\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\fse.node"
   "--module_name=fse"
   "--module_path=C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs
_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-mkvu1b\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\b
inding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32"
   gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\nod
e_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
   'C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
   configure --fallback-to-build
   --module=C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.
2\npm\node_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v
46-win32-ia32\fse.node
   --module_name=fse
   --module_path=C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\
2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\n
ode-v46-win32-ia32'
   (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
   (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
   (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-g
yp"
   "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\nod
e_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   npm ERR! argv
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
   "rebuild" "--update-binary"
   npm ERR! node v4.6.1
   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.14 install: `node-pre-gyp install
   --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.14 install script 'node-pre-gyp
   install --fallback-to-build'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
   installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents
   package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
   project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\nod
e_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\npm-debug.log
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download:
   https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.14/fse-v1.0.14-node
-v46-win32-ia32.tar.gz
   node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14 and
   node@4.6.1 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with
   node-gyp)
   gyp ERR! configure error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable
   "C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\python\python.exe",
   you can set the PYTHON env variable.
   gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython
   (C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
   gyp ERR! stack     at
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
   gyp ERR! stack     at
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
   "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
   "--module=C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs_mome
nt\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-mkvu1b\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\bindin
g\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32\\fse.node"
   "--module_name=fse"
   "--module_path=C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\momentjs
_moment\\2.15.2\\npm\\node_modules\\.temp-mkvu1b\\node_modules\\fsevents\\lib\\b
inding\\Release\\node-v46-win32-ia32"
   gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\nod
e_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
   gyp ERR! not ok
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
   'C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node.exe
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.window
s.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
   configure --fallback-to-build
   --module=C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.
2\npm\node_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\node-v
46-win32-ia32\fse.node
   --module_name=fse
   --module_path=C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\
2.15.2\npm\node_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents\lib\binding\Release\n
ode-v46-win32-ia32'
   (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2\mt-os.windo
ws.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
   (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
   (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-g
yp"
   "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\nod
e_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\node_modules\fsevents
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.6.1
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   npm ERR! argv
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe"
   "C:\\Users\\GA-PMC\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.4.2\\mt
-os.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\lib\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"
   "rebuild" "--update-binary"
   npm ERR! node v4.6.1
   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.14 install: `node-pre-gyp install
   --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.14 install script 'node-pre-gyp
   install --fallback-to-build'.
   npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
   installed.
   npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fsevents
   package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
   project with:
   npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   npm ERR!
   C:\Users\GA-PMC\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\momentjs_moment\2.15.2\npm\nod
e_modules\.temp-mkvu1b\npm-debug.log
```

Im sorry the file is so long but im not exactly sure where im looking for the error. Is it FS events or NodeJS? There seems to be older packages installed can I use these instead? How do I disable meteor from trying to get the latest version?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7960). You can try to change moment to v2.15.1 or upgrade to the beta using `meteor update --release 1.4.2.1-beta.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue running meteor 1.3.5.1 and moment 2.15.2

I fixed it by installing moment 2.15.1

```
meteor add momentjs:moment@=2.15.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install python. MDG made a change, so that each user needs to provide their own build chain tools, which means things like python, gyp etc.

So install python and try again, it should work for you